# Cordova Angular webView error Refused to apply inline style because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive

Tags: android, cordova, webview, angular8, content-security-policy

I am trying to convert my angular app to a cordova android application and although it works fine in browser, when I try to build and run on andorid, it build successfully but fails to show any content. After looking at the run log I see that I am getting a couple of script load failure due to Content Security Policy violation and I have looked around but no solution seems to work.

I get the following errors:

[image]

My index.html file for cordova in www is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script> if (global === undefined) { var global = window; } </script>
  <base href="/"/>
  <title>eServer</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <style>
    a {
      cursor: pointer
    }
  </style>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *; img-src 'self' data:">


  <!-- Then include bootstrap js -->
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <style type="text/css">@font-face{font-family:'Roboto';font-style:normal;font-weight:300;src:url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v20/KFOlCnqEu92Fr1MmSU5fBBc-.woff) format('woff');}@font-face{font-family:'Roboto';font-style:normal;font-weight:400;src:url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v20/KFOmCnqEu92Fr1Mu4mxM.woff) format('woff');}@font-face{font-family:'Roboto';font-style:normal;font-weight:500;src:url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v20/KFOlCnqEu92Fr1MmEU9fBBc-.woff) format('woff');}@font-face{font-family:'Roboto';font-style:normal;font-weight:300;src:url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v20/KFOlCnqEu92Fr1MmSU5fCRc4AMP6lbBP.woff2) format('woff2');unicode-range:U+0460-052F, U+1C80-1C88, U+20B4, U+2DE0-2DFF, U+A640-A69F, U+FE2E-FE2F;}@font-face{font-family:'Roboto';font-style:normal;font-weight:300;src:url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v20/KFOlCnqEu92Fr1MmSU5fABc4AMP6lbBP.woff2) format('woff2');unicode-range:U+0400-045F, U+0490-0491, U+04B0-04B1, U+2116;}@font-face{font-family:'Roboto';font-style:normal;font-weight:300;src:url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v20/KFOlCnqEu92Fr1MmSU5fCBc4AMP6lbBP.woff2) format('woff2');unicode-range:U+1F00-1FFF;}@font-face{font-family:'Roboto';font-style:normal;font-weight:300;src:url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v20/KFOlCnqEu92Fr1MmSU5fBxc4AMP6lbBP.woff2) format('woff2');unicode-range:U+0370-03FF;}@font-face{font-family:'Roboto';font-style:normal;font-weight:300;src:url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v20/KFOlCnqEu92Fr1MmSU5fCxc4AMP6lbBP.woff2) format('woff2');unicode-range:U+0102-0103, U+0110-0111, U+0128-0129, U+0168-0169, U+01A0-01A1, U+01AF-01B0, U+1EA0-1EF9, U+20AB;}@font-face{font-family:'Roboto';font-style:normal;font-weight:300;src:url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v20/KFOlCnqEu92Fr1MmSU5fChc4AMP6lbBP.woff2) format('woff2');unicode-range:U+0100-024F, U+0259, U+1E00-1EFF, U+2020, U+20A0-20AB, U+20AD-20CF, U+2113, U+2C60-2C7F, U+A720-A7FF;}@font-face{font-family:'Roboto';font-style:normal;font-weight:300;src:url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v20/KFOlCnqEu92Fr1MmSU5fBBc4AMP6lQ.woff2) format('woff2');unicode-range:U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02BB-02BC, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2122, U+2191, U+2193, U+2212, U+2215, U+FEFF, U+FFFD;}@font-face{font-family:'Roboto';font-style:normal;font-weight:400;src:url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v20/KFOmCnqEu92Fr1Mu72xKKTU1Kvnz.woff2) format('woff2');unicode-range:U+0460-052F, U+1C80-1C88, U+20B4, U+2DE0-2DFF, U+A640-A69F, U+FE2E-FE2F;}@font-face{font-family:'Roboto';font-style:normal;font-weight:400;src:url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v20/KFOmCnqEu92Fr1Mu5mxKKTU1Kvnz.woff2) format('woff2');unicode-range:U+0400-045F, U+0490-0491, U+04B0-04B1, U+2116;}@font-face{font-family:'Roboto';font-style:normal;font-weight:400;src:url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v20/KFOmCnqEu92Fr1Mu7mxKKTU1Kvnz.woff2) format('woff2');unicode-range:U+1F00-1FFF;}@font-face{font-family:'Roboto';font-style:normal;font-weight:400;src:url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v20/KFOmCnqEu92Fr1Mu4WxKKTU1Kvnz.woff2) format('woff2');unicode-range:U+0370-03FF;}@font-face{font-family:'Roboto';font-style:normal;font-weight:400;src:url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v20/KFOmCnqEu92Fr1Mu7WxKKTU1Kvnz.woff2) format('woff2');unicode-range:U+0102-0103, U+0110-0111, U+0128-0129, U+0168-0169, U+01A0-01A1, U+01AF-01B0, U+1EA0-1EF9, U+20AB;}@font-face{font-family:'Roboto';font-style:normal;font-weight:400;src:url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v20/KFOmCnqEu92Fr1Mu7GxKKTU1Kvnz.woff2) format('woff2');unicode-range:U+0100-024F, U+0259, U+1E00-1EFF, U+2020, U+20A0-20AB, U+20AD-20CF, U+2113, U+2C60-2C7F, U+A720-A7FF;}@font-face{font-family:'Roboto';font-style:normal;font-weight:400;src:url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v20/KFOmCnqEu92Fr1Mu4mxKKTU1Kg.woff2) format('woff2');unicode-range:U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02BB-02BC, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2122, U+2191, U+2193, U+2212, U+2215, U+FEFF, U+FFFD;}@font-face{font-family:'Roboto';font-style:normal;font-weight:500;src:url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v20/KFOlCnqEu92Fr1MmEU9fCRc4AMP6lbBP.woff2) format('woff2');unicode-range:U+0460-052F, U+1C80-1C88, U+20B4, U+2DE0-2DFF, U+A640-A69F, U+FE2E-FE2F;}@font-face{font-family:'Roboto';font-style:normal;font-weight:500;src:url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v20/KFOlCnqEu92Fr1MmEU9fABc4AMP6lbBP.woff2) format('woff2');unicode-range:U+0400-045F, U+0490-0491, U+04B0-04B1, U+2116;}@font-face{font-family:'Roboto';font-style:normal;font-weight:500;src:url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v20/KFOlCnqEu92Fr1MmEU9fCBc4AMP6lbBP.woff2) format('woff2');unicode-range:U+1F00-1FFF;}@font-face{font-family:'Roboto';font-style:normal;font-weight:500;src:url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v20/KFOlCnqEu92Fr1MmEU9fBxc4AMP6lbBP.woff2) format('woff2');unicode-range:U+0370-03FF;}@font-face{font-family:'Roboto';font-style:normal;font-weight:500;src:url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v20/KFOlCnqEu92Fr1MmEU9fCxc4AMP6lbBP.woff2) format('woff2');unicode-range:U+0102-0103, U+0110-0111, U+0128-0129, U+0168-0169, U+01A0-01A1, U+01AF-01B0, U+1EA0-1EF9, U+20AB;}@font-face{font-family:'Roboto';font-style:normal;font-weight:500;src:url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v20/KFOlCnqEu92Fr1MmEU9fChc4AMP6lbBP.woff2) format('woff2');unicode-range:U+0100-024F, U+0259, U+1E00-1EFF, U+2020, U+20A0-20AB, U+20AD-20CF, U+2113, U+2C60-2C7F, U+A720-A7FF;}@font-face{font-family:'Roboto';font-style:normal;font-weight:500;src:url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v20/KFOlCnqEu92Fr1MmEU9fBBc4AMP6lQ.woff2) format('woff2');unicode-range:U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02BB-02BC, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2122, U+2191, U+2193, U+2212, U+2215, U+FEFF, U+FFFD;}</style>
  <style type="text/css">@font-face{font-family:'Material Icons';font-style:normal;font-weight:400;src:url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/materialicons/v77/flUhRq6tzZclQEJ-Vdg-IuiaDsNa.woff) format('woff');}.material-icons{font-family:'Material Icons';font-weight:normal;font-style:normal;font-size:24px;line-height:1;letter-spacing:normal;text-transform:none;display:inline-block;white-space:nowrap;word-wrap:normal;direction:ltr;font-feature-settings:'liga';}@font-face{font-family:'Material Icons';font-style:normal;font-weight:400;src:url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/materialicons/v77/flUhRq6tzZclQEJ-Vdg-IuiaDsNcIhQ8tQ.woff2) format('woff2');}.material-icons{font-family:'Material Icons';font-weight:normal;font-style:normal;font-size:24px;line-height:1;letter-spacing:normal;text-transform:none;display:inline-block;white-space:nowrap;word-wrap:normal;direction:ltr;-webkit-font-feature-settings:'liga';-webkit-font-smoothing:antialiased;}</style>
  <style type="text/css">@font-face{font-family:'Material Icons';font-style:normal;font-weight:400;src:url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/materialicons/v77/flUhRq6tzZclQEJ-Vdg-IuiaDsNa.woff) format('woff');}.material-icons{font-family:'Material Icons';font-weight:normal;font-style:normal;font-size:24px;line-height:1;letter-spacing:normal;text-transform:none;display:inline-block;white-space:nowrap;word-wrap:normal;direction:ltr;font-feature-settings:'liga';}@font-face{font-family:'Material Icons';font-style:normal;font-weight:400;src:url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/materialicons/v77/flUhRq6tzZclQEJ-Vdg-IuiaDsNcIhQ8tQ.woff2) format('woff2');}.material-icons{font-family:'Material Icons';font-weight:normal;font-style:normal;font-size:24px;line-height:1;letter-spacing:normal;text-transform:none;display:inline-block;white-space:nowrap;word-wrap:normal;direction:ltr;-webkit-font-feature-settings:'liga';-webkit-font-smoothing:antialiased;}</style>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.indigo-pink.min.css">
  <script defer="" src="https://code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.min.js"></script>
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <style type="text/css">@font-face{font-family:'Roboto';font-style:normal;font-weight:300;font-display:swap;src:url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v20/KFOlCnqEu92Fr1MmSU5fBBc-.woff) format('woff');}@font-face{font-family:'Roboto';font-style:normal;font-weight:400;font-display:swap;src:url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v20/KFOmCnqEu92Fr1Mu4mxM.woff) format('woff');}@font-face{font-family:'Roboto';font-style:normal;font-weight:500;font-display:swap;src:url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v20/KFOlCnqEu92Fr1MmEU9fBBc-.woff) format('woff');}@font-face{font-family:'Roboto';font-style:normal;font-weight:300;font-display:swap;src:url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v20/KFOlCnqEu92Fr1MmSU5fCRc4AMP6lbBP.woff2) format('woff2');unicode-range:U+0460-052F, U+1C80-1C88, U+20B4, U+2DE0-2DFF, U+A640-A69F, U+FE2E-FE2F;}@font-face{font-family:'Roboto';font-style:normal;font-weight:300;font-display:swap;src:url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v20/KFOlCnqEu92Fr1MmSU5fABc4AMP6lbBP.woff2) format('woff2');unicode-range:U+0400-045F, U+0490-0491, U+04B0-04B1, U+2116;}@font-face{font-family:'Roboto';font-style:normal;font-weight:300;font-display:swap;src:url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v20/KFOlCnqEu92Fr1MmSU5fCBc4AMP6lbBP.woff2) format('woff2');unicode-range:U+1F00-1FFF;}@font-face{font-family:'Roboto';font-style:normal;font-weight:300;font-display:swap;src:url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v20/KFOlCnqEu92Fr1MmSU5fBxc4AMP6lbBP.woff2) format('woff2');unicode-range:U+0370-03FF;}@font-face{font-family:'Roboto';font-style:normal;font-weight:300;font-display:swap;src:url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v20/KFOlCnqEu92Fr1MmSU5fCxc4AMP6lbBP.woff2) format('woff2');unicode-range:U+0102-0103, U+0110-0111, U+0128-0129, U+0168-0169, U+01A0-01A1, U+01AF-01B0, U+1EA0-1EF9, U+20AB;}@font-face{font-family:'Roboto';font-style:normal;font-weight:300;font-display:swap;src:url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v20/KFOlCnqEu92Fr1MmSU5fChc4AMP6lbBP.woff2) format('woff2');unicode-range:U+0100-024F, U+0259, U+1E00-1EFF, U+2020, U+20A0-20AB, U+20AD-20CF, U+2113, U+2C60-2C7F, U+A720-A7FF;}@font-face{font-family:'Roboto';font-style:normal;font-weight:300;font-display:swap;src:url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v20/KFOlCnqEu92Fr1MmSU5fBBc4AMP6lQ.woff2) format('woff2');unicode-range:U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02BB-02BC, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2122, U+2191, U+2193, U+2212, U+2215, U+FEFF, U+FFFD;}@font-face{font-family:'Roboto';font-style:normal;font-weight:400;font-display:swap;src:url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v20/KFOmCnqEu92Fr1Mu72xKKTU1Kvnz.woff2) format('woff2');unicode-range:U+0460-052F, U+1C80-1C88, U+20B4, U+2DE0-2DFF, U+A640-A69F, U+FE2E-FE2F;}@font-face{font-family:'Roboto';font-style:normal;font-weight:400;font-display:swap;src:url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v20/KFOmCnqEu92Fr1Mu5mxKKTU1Kvnz.woff2) format('woff2');unicode-range:U+0400-045F, U+0490-0491, U+04B0-04B1, U+2116;}@font-face{font-family:'Roboto';font-style:normal;font-weight:400;font-display:swap;src:url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v20/KFOmCnqEu92Fr1Mu7mxKKTU1Kvnz.woff2) format('woff2');unicode-range:U+1F00-1FFF;}@font-face{font-family:'Roboto';font-style:normal;font-weight:400;font-display:swap;src:url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v20/KFOmCnqEu92Fr1Mu4WxKKTU1Kvnz.woff2) format('woff2');unicode-range:U+0370-03FF;}@font-face{font-family:'Roboto';font-style:normal;font-weight:400;font-display:swap;src:url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v20/KFOmCnqEu92Fr1Mu7WxKKTU1Kvnz.woff2) format('woff2');unicode-range:U+0102-0103, U+0110-0111, U+0128-0129, U+0168-0169, U+01A0-01A1, U+01AF-01B0, U+1EA0-1EF9, U+20AB;}@font-face{font-family:'Roboto';font-style:normal;font-weight:400;font-display:swap;src:url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v20/KFOmCnqEu92Fr1Mu7GxKKTU1Kvnz.woff2) format('woff2');unicode-range:U+0100-024F, U+0259, U+1E00-1EFF, U+2020, U+20A0-20AB, U+20AD-20CF, U+2113, U+2C60-2C7F, U+A720-A7FF;}@font-face{font-family:'Roboto';font-style:normal;font-weight:400;font-display:swap;src:url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v20/KFOmCnqEu92Fr1Mu4mxKKTU1Kg.woff2) format('woff2');unicode-range:U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02BB-02BC, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2122, U+2191, U+2193, U+2212, U+2215, U+FEFF, U+FFFD;}@font-face{font-family:'Roboto';font-style:normal;font-weight:500;font-display:swap;src:url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v20/KFOlCnqEu92Fr1MmEU9fCRc4AMP6lbBP.woff2) format('woff2');unicode-range:U+0460-052F, U+1C80-1C88, U+20B4, U+2DE0-2DFF, U+A640-A69F, U+FE2E-FE2F;}@font-face{font-family:'Roboto';font-style:normal;font-weight:500;font-display:swap;src:url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v20/KFOlCnqEu92Fr1MmEU9fABc4AMP6lbBP.woff2) format('woff2');unicode-range:U+0400-045F, U+0490-0491, U+04B0-04B1, U+2116;}@font-face{font-family:'Roboto';font-style:normal;font-weight:500;font-display:swap;src:url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v20/KFOlCnqEu92Fr1MmEU9fCBc4AMP6lbBP.woff2) format('woff2');unicode-range:U+1F00-1FFF;}@font-face{font-family:'Roboto';font-style:normal;font-weight:500;font-display:swap;src:url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v20/KFOlCnqEu92Fr1MmEU9fBxc4AMP6lbBP.woff2) format('woff2');unicode-range:U+0370-03FF;}@font-face{font-family:'Roboto';font-style:normal;font-weight:500;font-display:swap;src:url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v20/KFOlCnqEu92Fr1MmEU9fCxc4AMP6lbBP.woff2) format('woff2');unicode-range:U+0102-0103, U+0110-0111, U+0128-0129, U+0168-0169, U+01A0-01A1, U+01AF-01B0, U+1EA0-1EF9, U+20AB;}@font-face{font-family:'Roboto';font-style:normal;font-weight:500;font-display:swap;src:url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v20/KFOlCnqEu92Fr1MmEU9fChc4AMP6lbBP.woff2) format('woff2');unicode-range:U+0100-024F, U+0259, U+1E00-1EFF, U+2020, U+20A0-20AB, U+20AD-20CF, U+2113, U+2C60-2C7F, U+A720-A7FF;}@font-face{font-family:'Roboto';font-style:normal;font-weight:500;font-display:swap;src:url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v20/KFOlCnqEu92Fr1MmEU9fBBc4AMP6lQ.woff2) format('woff2');unicode-range:U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02BB-02BC, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2122, U+2191, U+2193, U+2212, U+2215, U+FEFF, U+FFFD;}</style>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.fdd7266db81e3eef431f.css"></head>
<body style="background-color: white;">
<app-root>
  <div class="load">
    <div class="spinner-border" style="width: 10rem; height: 10rem;" role="status">
    </div>
  </div>
</app-root>
<script src="runtime-es2015.a1ac991fc00ebf39524f.js" type="module"></script><script src="runtime-es5.a1ac991fc00ebf39524f.js" nomodule="" defer=""></script><script src="polyfills-es5.094844995b3942c734b7.js" nomodule="" defer=""></script><script src="polyfills-es2015.a609278fc48624530e25.js" type="module"></script><script src="scripts.a963d69ada6021ca7963.js" defer=""></script><script src="main-es2015.2c3d7929b035949bc279.js" type="module"></script><script src="main-es5.2c3d7929b035949bc279.js" nomodule="" defer=""></script></body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fixed with:

`<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *; img-src 'self' data:">` in the index the html in the www folder.

Answer (score 1):

`Refused to load script https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdm.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/... because it's violates ... directive "script-src ..."` means you have to add `https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdm.com` to the `script-src` directive.

`Refused to load stylesheet https://code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/... because it's violates ... directive "style-src ..."` means you have to add `https://code.getmdl.io` to the `style-src` directive.

And so on. Fix all rules in the `<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="...">`

Note: I do not know why do you use `<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy`, but you need to have manifest for Web app or Web Extension. CSP should be specified in the `content_security_policy_key` key for manifest V2. Otherwise you will have [default CSP](https://csplite.com/csp268/#default_CSP) `"script-src 'self'; object-src 'self';"`.